# Ubuntu Touch: unity8 at 100% cpu usage

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Running Ubuntu Touch 15.04 on a Nexus 5.

This unity8 process is constantly hovering between 96 and 100% CPU usage, never dipping any lower. I suspect this is what is causing my battery to completely drain in under two hours at idle!

Please, any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is obsolete and Unity 8 is still in preview phase. A more common configuration might be better for your battery.

Comment: @Melebius Ubuntu 15.04 is valid for Ubuntu phones.